# drawn lines get fade during deletion of text

Tags: objective-c, uitextview, drawrect

To make the lines in textview programmatically I have implemented following code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [super drawRect:rect];
    CGSize textSize = [alpha sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"FreeHand575" size:28.0]
    constrainedToSize:self.contentSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping];
    NSUInteger height = textSize.height;
    textSize = [self.text sizeWithFont:self.font constrainedToSize:self.contentSize       
    lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping];
    NSUInteger contentHeight = (rect.size.height > textSize.height) ?  
   (NSUInteger)rect.size.height : textSize.height;
    NSUInteger offset = height; 
   CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, .8, .8, .8, 1);
   for(int i=offset;i < contentHeight;i+=height) {
      CGPoint lpoints[2] = { CGPointMake(0, i), CGPointMake(rect.size.width, i) };
      CGContextStrokeLineSegments(ctx, lpoints, 2);
   }}
```

It is working perfectly. But the issue come when user delete the text from textview and some time some place drawn line also get delete or fade.

[image: textview with fade lines]

I am unable to find the issue. If anyone has some idea please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you try writing this line [super drawRect:rect];in last??

Comment: @hussainShabbir Yes I tried but didn't resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

You could add a layer below the main layer for the textview and draw the lines on that. That way the drawing text(or delete) won't affect the lines.
Read [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2502/calayers-tutorial-for-ios-introduction-to-calayers-tutorial) to see how to draw on a layer, see "CALayer and Custom Drawn Content".